# iOS Shortcut; VPN status

Tags: ios, vpn, shortcuts-app

I have very basic knowledge of iOS shortcuts. I know how to create a shortcut to toggle VPN on/off, to create a shortcut to turn VPN on/off and then trigger the shortcut in certain situations like when I join a certain network using "Automation".

My question: is there a way to create a shortcut that checks the VPN status (on or off and which VPN network I am connected to) and displays the same in a widget on my home screen?

Also is there a resource that one can use to learn to use shortcuts with step by step instructions?

Thanks in advance for any input your can provide on this matter.